# Retrieving multiple documents as custom object in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I have a React application connected to Firestore. I followed the official documentation on [adding custom objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) to Firestore via the help of `withConverter` function.

Now I want to read all the data I uploaded to Firestore into my app as a custom object again. But the documentation on Firestore did not show how to pull it off. The documentation only showed [getting one document as custom objec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) and [get multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection). But not a combination of both which I need.

Maybe I'm missing out some concepts, am I not supposed to get multiple documents as custom objects or something else? Any help is very much appreciated!

My data converter function:

```js
const dataConverter = {
    toFirestore: (stock) => {
        return {
            brand: stock.brand,
            model: stock.model,
            serialNum: stock.serialNum,
            stock: stock.stock,
            location: stock.location,
            date: stock.date,
            inventoryUID: stock.inventoryUID
        }
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) => {
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new Stocks(data.brand, data.model, data.serialNum, data.stock, data.location, data.date, data.inventoryUID);
    }
}
```

Let me know if any additional information is required. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `withConverter` before, but given that a [`Query` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) also has a `withConverter` method, I expect you just call that on the `Query` object similar to how you call it on a `DocumentReference`:

```
// for a single document
const ref = doc(db, "cities", "LA").withConverter(cityConverter);

// for multiple documents
const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true))
            .withConverter(cityConverter);
```

Comment: Oh my this works, thanks for the help! I did not realize that there was a `withConverter` method for Query. Interestingly, this was not included in the documentation. Or maybe I overlooked it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I linked the documentation that I used to determine where the method exists. I recommend keeping the reference documentation handy too, as the guides may not cover all use-cases you have.